# Android application Screen dim according to time

Tags: android, screen

i have a application and now i want to add dim screen type of functionality in this feature application screen light gets dim according to given time and when user touch on screen it again resume. so please tell me how i can achieve it i have used this peace of code

```
                        time = 30000;

        android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, time);
```

it is dim the screen but device is goes into sleep mode i dont want this situation please help me .